# WCF: How to have implementation logic in a separate project to contract interface?

Tags: c#, wcf

like the title says, I want to keep my logic in a separate project to the service contract(s) so this can stay separate and hidden. I've seen it said that this can be done, but I can't find any examples as to how.

I moved all the necessary code out to a different project, but when I test it only the types are visible to the client, not the methods.

All the methods are marked as `[OperationContract]` in the interface.

I'm guessing there must be a way of specifically connecting the implementation logic to the contract other than just `Class : IInterface`, otherwise, what would happen if there were 2 similar classes, e.g.: `Class1 : IInterface` and `Class2 : IInterface`? How would WCF know which class to use?

Comment: Perhaps you missed `public` access modifier for the methods?

Comment: Good point - I had to check! But no, they are all public.

Comment: You can even wire up Ioc, so you can control how implementation is bound to interface, but I'm pretty sure that even with default factory it is possible to keep implementation in separate assembly.

Comment: What is your projects order (reference order)?

Comment: @Amiram Korach The implementation project references the contracts project (otherwise it wouldn't see the interface!) - is that what you meant?

Comment: Did you changed the namespace of your interfaces? Did you add a project reference or file reference?

Comment: @Amiram Korach I added a project reference and yes I changed the namespaces; do these need to be identical? It didn;t seem to make a difference when I tried it. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need to define the services in the web.config explicitly. Since .NET 4 they don't appear there automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would WCF know which class to use?

Because you tell it, in the various configuration files.

---

I can heartily recommend [WCF the Manual Way…the Right Way](http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/39837/1954) for motivation and a complete walkthrough for what you are trying to do - what I have here is just the pertinent points of such an implementation.

You have three assemblies: `Service`, `Client`, `ServiceContracts` (interfaces only). `Service` and `Client` both reference `ServiceContracts`. `Service` contains classes implementing the interfaces. `Client` has **proxy** classes:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using ServiceContracts;

public class ExampleServiceProxy : ClientBase<IExampleService>, IExampleService
{
    public string ExampleMethod()
    {
        return Channel.ExampleMethod();
    }
}
```

The client's `config` file contains an entry pointing at the service's `svc` file; the service's `svc` file looks like this:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Service.ExampleService" 
    CodeBehind="ExampleService.svc.cs" %>
```

And the service `.svc.cs` file looks like:

```
using ServiceContracts;

public class ExampleService : IExampleService
{
    public string ExampleMethod()
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

That's it!

Comment: Thanks, but still confused. (1) Where is the ServiceContract config that says which Service class to use? (2) The client config you've given looks like the Service config file; where can I find this for the client? Sorry for being slow...

Comment: @bukko `ServiceContract` is *just* an interface with `[ServiceContract]` containing methods with `[OperationContract]` - it doesn't know anything about its implementations. The client config will have an `<endpoint` in its `<system.serviceModel>`, giving the location of the `svc` file that I've shown. It's all in the blogpost I linked to :)

Comment: My test client does have an endpoint, but it points to the interface (`contract="SVC.IMyContract"`).

Comment: [The `<endpoint` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731762.aspx), as well as the `contract` attribute giving the *type* of the contract, will also have an `address` attribute giving the *location* of something that leads to the actual implementation. See [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731144.aspx)

Comment: Yup I saw that (tried to edit my comment too late!). So it's the address which indicates the real endpoint. Back to my original problem: why aren't my methods visible??

Comment: That I don't know. Depending on how you have projects/solutions structured, it may be that you need some judicious rebuilding.

Comment: I think you're right :( Thanks very much for the help, it's been educational!

Comment: It works now. I don't know what was wrong, and probably never will! Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 11):

I've done it this way (sorry for bad names, that's just for concept):

1) Created separate project for implementation
2) Created separate project for service contract (to avoid circular references)
3) Added service contract project as reference to implementation project
4) Added contract and implementation project to host project
5) Updated Service.svc with full type name

[image]

Service.svc body:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Implementation.ServiceImplementation" %>
```

Comment: Thank you.but in host solution i don't know how can i add my service to svc file .could you please give me some infomation about this .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151796/iis-shows-1-service-instead-of-two-service-in-my-project-c-sharp-wcf

Comment: Thanks! this was what I am looking for. :)

Comment: project Implementation and Contract: what are the types of those projects? WCF Class Library or regular .NET Framework Class Library?

Comment: I has been long time since I last time touched WCF, but I think you can start with regular .NET Framework class library and if will need, add missing references manually - that way you'll avoid having references you did not need in first place.